# C#: SqlCeParameter DbType for nVarChar?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

First off, I like specifying data types and I despise `AddWithValue` functions.

I'm building an SqlCeServer 3.5 local database Application under .NET 4.0 that will run on users PC.

When I created the table, I use `NVarChar(50)` to specify my string fields.

This seems to work fine, and I can open the table to verify everything worked well in *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008*.

When I insert data into my tables, I use

```
public static SqlCeParameter ParameterString(string ColumnName, string value) {
  SqlCeParameter p = new SqlCeParameter();
  p.ParameterName = string.Format("@{0}", ColumnName);
  p.DataType = DbType.String;
  p.Size = 50;
  p.Value = value;
  return p;
}
```

When I insert this data, there are no errors, but the data is not inserted. Other data types (`int`, `DateTime`, `float`, etc.) are inserting with no problems.

**Q: Is there some other `DbType` I need to specify to insert as `NVarChar`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DbType` enum is generic for all databases, so it doesn't contain all data types specific for SQL Server. Use an `SqlDbType`:

```
SqlCeParameter p = new SqlCeParameter(ColumnName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
p.Value = value;
```

Comment: You guys are FAST! So, should I cast `SqlDbType.NVarChar` back to a `DbType` for my `SqlCeParameter`? Right now, VS2010 tells me, "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to 'System.Data.DbType'. An exlicit conversion exists (are you misssing a cast?)*" If I'm casting, is that cast not available in the `DbType` enumeration?

Comment: Looking at the meta data from each, I see that the value of `SqlDbType.NVarChar` is 12, and the value of 12 under the meta data for `DbType` is `Int64`. **{UGH!}** Certainly not what I would have thought!

Comment: @jp2code: According to this the constructor should take an `SqlDbType`, not `DbType`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cbw9e693%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: +1 Thanks *Guffa*. I simply did not scroll all the way down the list of Properties that Intellisense displayed after I typed in the "." (`SqlDbType` was further down the list after `DbType`)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason there's two properties that you can use to set the type, [`DbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparameter.dbtype.aspx) and [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparameter.sqldbtype.aspx). According to MSDN:

> SqlDbType and DbType are linked. Therefore, setting the DbType changes the SqlDbType to a supporting SqlDbType.

So `SqlDbType` is the primary type, setting just `DbType` changes it to something close.

You might also want to read up on [this post](http://csharponphone.blogspot.com/2006/08/sqlceparameter-bug.html) where they had a problem when specifying `Length`s greater than 255.

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
SqlDbType.NVarChar
```

I hope this helps